# Codename one ,how to kill web browser instance after close form

Tags: codenameone

i have webpage in my form when i close form and reopen it the web page say :

> this page is already in progress from this browser instance. plz Close
>   the old instance.

how to close all browser instance when i close the form

BR,

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke `destroy()` on the browser component.

Comment: Dear Shai,
i tried these lines of code on exit form and before show and all of them not working
`myWebBrowser.clearClientProperties();`
`myWebBrowser.invalidate();`
`myWebBrowser.destroy();`
`myWebBrowser.stop();`

BR,

Comment: It's possible that the site is blocking you based on IP in which case you might need to logout for this to work properly. That isn't an error from our side of the code.